# Ignore Word List

Tags: javascript, regex, variables, replace

I have a list of words to ignore.  However, when I call it, it replaces every instance of it even when it's inside a string.

For example: "he" ends up turning "the" into "t".

How can I have it just remove the words when they're on their own?

Here's the code:

```
var commonWords=/and|a|an|has|he|to|was|in|were|are|is|will|as|it|if|
with|at|its|it's|be|by|on|that|from|the|about|again|all|almost|also|although|
always|among|another|any|be|because|been|before|being|between|both|by|can|could|
did|do|does|doesn't|'|done|due|during|each|either|enough|from|had|has|have|having|
here|i|if|into|is|isn't|itself|just|may|might|most|mostly|must|nor|no|neither|nearly|
of|often|on|our|ours|his|hers|he's|he|she|she's|overall|perhaps|quite|rather|really|
regarding|seem|seems|seen|several|should|show|showewd|shown|shows|significant|
significantly|since|so|some|such|than|that|then|their|theirs|there's|therefore|these|
they|this|those|through|thus|to|upon|use|used|using|various|very|was|we|were|what|when|
which|while|with|within|without|would|however|or|for|the|but|etc|yet|/g;

commonWords.ignoreCase;

var w = w.replace(commonWords, '');
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're not trying to replace any instance in a string, you want to replace whole words. You need to look for [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) using the `\b` anchor.

For example...

```
var commonWords = /\b(and|a|an|has|he|she)\b/g;
```